# How to Upload a folder to shared google drive using python google drive api?

Tags: google-drive-api

Code mentioned in https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder works for My Drive. No luck Using:

````
file_metadata = {
            'supportsAllDrives':True,
            'driveId': '0AGRl',
            'name': "new folderrrrr",
            'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
        }

file = DRIVE.files().create(body=file_metadata,
                            fields='id', supportsAllDrives=True, supportsTeamDrives=True).execute()```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

`'driveId': '0AGRl'`

through

`"parents": ["0AGRl"]`

Comment: Thank you. I have a requirement to create the subfolder in the shared drive. Help is appreciated!!